# JspTagException: No resolvable message -- Weblogic 12.2 and Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, weblogic

We are trying to upgrade our application from Spring 4 to Spring 5 (5.2.6).

As part of this change we have replaced all the jars build the application and deployed in WebLogic Server.

But while access a specific jsp page I am getting the below exception but I am not getting why and how to resolve it.

```
<ERROR> <HTTP> <BEA-101017> <ServletContext@234560000[app:ticketapp module:/ path:null spec-version:3.1]] Root cause of ServletException>
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No resolvable message
at org.spingframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.resolveMessage(MessageTag.java:338)
at org.spingframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doEndTag(MessageTag.java:274)
at jsp_servlet._ticketprocessing.__ticketdetails._jsp_tag0(_ticketdetails.java:544)
at jsp_servlet._ticketprocessing.__ticketdetails._jspService(_ticketdetails.java:330)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.serviceInternal(JspBase.java:35)
```

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'errors.contact.sysadmin.msg' for locale 'en\_US'.\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081844/javax-servlet-jsp-jsptagexception-no-message-found-under-code-errors-contact-s)

Comment: @AnishB. I already checked this but this didnt help. but I have one doubt, i saw in out application there is no messageSource bean is defined. this might cause this issue ?
but this is working fine in Spring 4

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
That is how I resolved it:

I had the following tag: <spring:message var="variable"/>

checking the source code of MessageTag here:

http://www.java2s.com/example/java-src/pkg/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/messagetag-d6db3.html

I was able to see what was triggering the exception, I had no code, text or message set up:

[Method of the MessageTag class that was triggering the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXKEZ.png)

So I changed my tag to:

<spring:message text="${variable}"/>

And it worked.